# Add custom field in cash on delivery as Account Id Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, checkout-page, cash-on-delivery

I need to add custom field when cash on delivery is selected it should be placed right below the COD radio button.

This field have to be saved with the order.

I tried with some articles But I cant get the logic to place them on the place.

Kindly advice me on this, We have onepage checkout.

With this links I can add custom fields on the payment form but Cant achieve my requirement.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

https://ranasohel.me/2015/11/28/how-to-add-custom-field-to-shipping-address-form-in-magento-2-onepage-checkout/
[image]

Comment: is this custom file related with code like instruction  or  it is just a custom  checkout field

Comment: are you looking to add it below radio button?

Comment: Its a customer checkout field, This field will be used my the merchant to have some verification of account when COD is applied. This field show for both logged in and guest user. For logged in user the field must contain the value if its been provided on the previous sale.

Comment: Yes I need it below Radio button.

Comment: I am new to Magento so I am not aware of the table it should be stored and the block I should work with, How to handle this the flow to work.

Comment: Can anyone help on this i.e how to add an input field below COD radio button and that input data show save on order database?.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146364)

Comment: Am in an emergency, can anyone help me to sort out this?.